# How to add website link in this popup code?

Tags: javascript, html, web, popup

hello I have this popup code now I want to switch to the web link when a user clicks on the image.  Please help me, thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var delay = 5000; // 5 seconds

setTimeout(function(){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            src: 'img/bg-corporate-20-2.jpg'
        },
        type: 'image'
    });
}, delay);
```

});

Comment: how is this even closely java related?

Answer (score 0):

i haven't used the framework you are using, but the documentation https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html 
is pretty cool to read, so i hope this works for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var delay = 5000; // 5 seconds

setTimeout(function(){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
        src: $('<a href="http://example/where/you/go" tagret="_blank"><img src="img/bg-corporate-20-2.jpg"></a>')
        },
        type: 'inline'
    });
}, delay);
});
```